# Retrieving children from children in firebase with Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve the posts from all the users in Ionic(without having the specific user id). I can get all the posts from the first user in the database, but am having trouble with getting the posts from the other users.

This is a simplified version of my firebase structure:

```
"posts_meta" : {

   "uid" : {

     "post-id" : {
        "title": "",
        "content": ""
     },
   },

   "uid" : {

     "post-id" : {
        "title": "",
        "content": ""
     },
     "post-id" : {
        "title": "",
        "content": ""
     },
   }
```

And here I'm trying to loop through the users first and then loop through the posts for each user by using a nested foreach:

```
.factory('Timeline', function($q, Profile, Utils, Codes) {

var self = this;

self.getAllPosts = function() {
    var qGet = $q.defer();
    var ref = new Firebase(FBURL);

    ref.child("posts_meta").once("value", function(snapshot) {

        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

            childSnapshot.forEach(function(grandchildSnapshot) {
                qGet.resolve(grandchildSnapshot.val());
            })
        })
}, function (error) {
        Codes.handleError(error);
        qGet.reject(error);
    });
    return qGet.promise;
};
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call multiple resolves for a single promise. The promise is being resolved in the first loop iteration and then the others are being ignored.

You can try save all granchilds to an array, but I believe firebase has its ways to solve this with a better performance.

```
    var values = [];

    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {

        childSnapshot.forEach(function(grandchildSnapshot) {
            values.push(grandchildSnapshot);

        })
     })
     promise.resolve(values)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved my problem. Worth to note that at first I didn't get the data correctly, but after changing the next line it worked perfectly:
values.push(grandchildSnapshot); to values.push(grandchildSnapshot.val());